# Pitest is failing showing: No mutations found due to the supplied classpath or filters + Gradle

Tags: apache-spark, gradle, intellij-idea, mutation-testing, pitest

I'm trying to run a pitest report on a gradle + kotlin project, but I get the following error:

Exception in thread "main" org.pitest.help.PitHelpError: No mutations found. This probably means there is an issue with either the supplied classpath or filters.
See http://pitest.org for more details.
at org.pitest.mutationtest.tooling.MutationCoverage.checkMutationsFound(MutationCoverage.java:352)
at org.pitest.mutationtest.tooling.MutationCoverage.runReport(MutationCoverage.java:132)
at org.pitest.mutationtest.tooling.EntryPoint.execute(EntryPoint.java:123)
at org.pitest.mutationtest.tooling.EntryPoint.execute(EntryPoint.java:54)
at org.pitest.mutationtest.commandline.MutationCoverageReport.runReport(MutationCoverageReport.java:98)
at org.pitest.mutationtest.commandline.MutationCoverageReport.main(MutationCoverageReport.java:45)

I tried everything that I found on google but still not working for me:
This is my build.gradle config

```
plugins {
id 'groovy-gradle-plugin'
id 'info.solidsoft.pitest' version '1.7.4'
}

repositories {
maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
gradlePluginPortal()
}


dependencies {
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.20'
implementation 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:6.1.0'
}


pitest {
targetClasses = ['com.project.root.to.test.with.pitest.src*']  //by default 
"${project.group}.*"
pitestVersion = '1.7.4' //not needed when a default PIT version should be used
threads = 4
outputFormats = ['XML', 'HTML']
timestampedReports = false
}
```

I tried this targetClasses in a different ways:

```
targetClasses = ['com.project.root.to.test.with.pitest.src.*']  //by default 
targetClasses = ['com/project/root/to/test/with/pitest/src*']  //by default
```

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

You look to be trying to supply pitest with a source folder

```
com.project.root.to.test.with.pitest.src.
```

Pitest works against the compiled bytecode, not the source files. It expects
a glob that matches against the package.

```
com.example.*
```

Comment: Hi Henry, I tried with com.project.* and I got the same result:

Exception in thread "main" org.pitest.help.PitHelpError: No mutations found. This probably means there is an issue with either the supplied classpath or filters.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this same issue today. You'll need to make sure all references to pitest use the same version 1.7.4. This includes

- plugin: id 'info.solidsoft.pitest' version '1.7.4'
- pitestVersion: pitestVersion.set('1.7.4')
- dependency: testCompile
  'info.solidsoft.gradle.pitest:gradle-pitest-plugin:1.7.4'

Which out changing all references, then it will break.